# Is the choice of dimension when constructing parametrization of surfaces is always 2 regardless of the dimension of which the surface is in?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

To parametrize a surface, it seems that, at least at the introductory level (my level T_T) that most text books simply define the parametrization of a surface in the real space to be the vector valued function $g:{\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3}$ without much justification of the dimension of which the domain of $g$ is defined on. I would like to use $g$ to always represent the parametrization function.

Some justification that I have seem is that a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be represented as combinations of two curves on linearly independent axises, and hence two variables would be sufficient to represent a surface. Or that a surface is simply a plane twisted ( in certain ways? ).

However as I would like to get a more complete picture. I wonder if there could be anything wrong with constructing such parametrization with the functions $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$ as well (for a surface also in $\mathbb{R}^3$), or is it perhaps just the ease of computation that we are to do so only in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Furthermore, would it then be true to state that all surface regardless of the dimension of the whole space it is in, i.e. a surface in $\mathbb{R}^N$, can be represented as a function $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus is there any abstract surface that have to be represented by $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^N$ (manifold?),

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the definition of surface to be? (And in particular, how would you distinguish it from a "solid lump" of $\mathbb{R}^3$?)

Comment: At my level it seems that the most reasonable answer is to say that a surface is, well, a infinitely thin paper twisted; and that a solid lump can be thought of as the scalar integral on that surface.

Comment: But I was thinking that in higher dimensions there could be some analogue of surface as well.

Comment: You may change the original definition of a parametrized surface into any embedding $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ for $m\leq n$. You can show that for any two parametrizations $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^{m'}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $m$ has to equal $m'$. Thus the dimension of a parametrized manifold is well-defined. A surface usually means a parametrized manifold of dimension 2.

Comment: Thank you! This solves my problem!